# I got an error while installing pytorch geometric

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

```
Collecting torch_geometric
  Using cached torch_geometric-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (63 kB)
Collecting tqdm (from torch_geometric)
  Using cached tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./studysession/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch_geometric) (1.24.4)
Collecting scipy (from torch_geometric)
  Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.3.0
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-install-ehjtf2q1/scipy_72142813be08402eb78bda14b44dce74
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-install-ehjtf2q1/scipy_72142813be08402eb78bda14b44dce74/.mesonpy-7jchm485/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.1
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld64 650.9
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 12.0.5 "Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld64 650.9
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.36)
      Host machine cpu family: aarch64
      Host machine cpu: aarch64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: YES
      Library m found: YES
      Fortran compiler for the host machine: gfortran (gcc 13.2.0 "GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0")
      Fortran linker for the host machine: gfortran ld64 650.9
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
      Checking if "-Wl,--version-script" : links: NO
      Program cython found: YES (/private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ynxo0jet/overlay/bin/cython)
      Program python found: YES (/Users/seonguk.park.26/Desktop/Exoplanet Detection/studysession/bin/python3)
      Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
      Found pkg-config: NO
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.8
      Program pythran found: YES (/private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-ynxo0jet/overlay/bin/pythran)
      Run-time dependency threads found: YES
      Library npymath found: YES
      Library npyrandom found: YES
      Did not find CMake 'cmake'
      Found CMake: NO
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
      Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried framework)
      
      ../../scipy/meson.build:134:7: ERROR: Dependency lookup for OpenBLAS with method 'pkgconfig' failed: Pkg-config for machine 1 not found. Giving up.
      
      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-install-ehjtf2q1/scipy_72142813be08402eb78bda14b44dce74/.mesonpy-7jchm485/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      + meson setup --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8 /private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-install-ehjtf2q1/scipy_72142813be08402eb78bda14b44dce74 /private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-install-ehjtf2q1/scipy_72142813be08402eb78bda14b44dce74/.mesonpy-7jchm485/build --native-file=/private/var/folders/t4/cysfkq790d9_cjtr07wb0phh0000gn/T/pip-install-ehjtf2q1/scipy_72142813be08402eb78bda14b44dce74/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Ran pip install torch_geometric in a virtual environment in vscode and got an error. (python version: 3.8.2, pytorch version: 2.1.0)

Comment: What OS are you using? Looks like some dependencies are missing.